# Integral of $1/z$ over $\partial D(0,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've seen in my book that $$\int_{\partial D(0,1)} \frac{dz}{z}=1$$.

When I try to prove it, I have:

$$\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{1/z}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt/e^{it}}dt=0$$

Could you please help me see my error?
Thank you!

Comment: I've improved the formatting, see if it is what you meant now (not sure what you meant in the last integral).

Comment: The value of the integral is $2\pi i$, not $1$.

Comment: Hard to explain what the error is - I have no idea what the notation $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt/e^{it}}{dt}$ even _means_...

Comment: Sorry for the error, when asking a question on the mobile site there is no real time formatting of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Note that by letting $z=e^{it}$ then $dz=e^{it}i\,dt$, therefore
$$\int_{\partial D(0,1)} \frac{dz}{z}=\int_{t=0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{it}i\,dt}{e^{it}}.$$
Can you take it from here?

P.S. You should obtain $2\pi i$ and not $1$.